# Cheerio scraping: Not able to find elements in HTML response

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have a HTML response as:

```
<table id="\&quot;tableone\&quot;" class="\&quot;sortable">
```

Now ,when I tries to find element with the ID #tableone ,it returns nothing but if I try to find using 'table' it works.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html)
console.log('tableone:'+ $('#tableone').length)          => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery's wild card selector. In your case you can use the `*` selector which will fetch all matching entries which matches the term `tableone`

You can try like this,

```
console.log('tableone:'+ $('[id*=tableone]').length);
```

Hope this helps!